# OpenCVAndroid Imgproc.GaussianBlur application stopped

Tags: android, opencv, filter, gaussian

I'm newbie OCV and android developer. I want Imgproc.GaussianBlur filter in my app. When i use it application send "application stopped". I only add 3 lines to "OpenCV Tutorial 3 - Camera Control":

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat mat = inputFrame.gray();
    org.opencv.core.Size s = mat.size();
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mat, mat, s, 2);
    return mat;
}
```

What could be wrong? I have Lenovo A820 Android 4.1.2 and tried it on OpenCV 2.4.4, 2.4.5 and 2.4.6. I tried different API. The `Imgproc.Sobel(mat,mat,-1,1,1);` filter works good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

look at the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#gaussianblur) for GaussianBlur

it says: "ksize – Gaussian kernel size. ksize.width and ksize.height can differ but they both must be positive and odd."

so, imho, you confused the kernel size with the Mat's size, try something like:

```
Mat mat = inputFrame.gray();
org.opencv.core.Size s = new Size(3,3);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mat, mat, s, 2);
return mat;
```

Comment: I'm confused. The metod mat.size() return type org.opencv.core.Size When I click link in description of GaussianBlur this is the same Size. I use http://docs.opencv.org/java/. What function of size do you suggest? camera.size don't work.

Comment: i meant , create a *new* Size object for the kernel. see edit above

Comment: let me clarify this , again: the size of the kernel is the region around any pixel, that you want interpolated, *not* the image size.